# How to use mc name to access a variable

Tags: actionscript

I have a form with a variety of buttons available for selection by the user. I already have variables set up for each button on the main timeline which are meant to hold the values "yes" or "no" depending on whether the button was selected or not. They all start off with a "no".

Here is the array for each button:

```
tabs_array = ["familiars","tallers2","gestions","sortides","tallers1","medic","podoleg","dutxes","menjador"];
```

Here are the initial variables for whether the buttons have been selected or not:

```
var send_dutxes:String="no";
var send_gestions:String="no";
var send_medic:String="no";
var send_menjador:String="no";
var send_podoleg:String="no";
var send_sortides:String="no";
var send_tallers1:String="no";
var send_tallers2:String="no";
var send_familiars:String="no";
```

Here is the code for each button:

```
for(var a=0; a<tabs_array.length; a++){
this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].gotoAndStop("off");
this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, act_over);
this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, act_out);
this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleAct);
this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].buttonMode = true;
}
```

Here is the code for where I'm having the issue (the click state)...when the user clicks one of the selections:

```
    function toggleAct(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (this("send_"+event.currentTarget.name)=="no")
    {
        event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("on");
        trace("changing no to yes");
        this("send_"+event.currentTarget.name) = "yes";
    }
    else if (this("send_"+event.currentTarget.name)=="yes")
    {
        event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop("off");
        this("send_"+event.currentTarget.name) = "no";
        trace("changing yes to no");
    }
}
```

Basically I need to know how to connect the mc name that was clicked to the corresponding variable....changing a string into a variable name.

Comment: `mc`? What's `mc`? And while that does look like javascript, you haven't indicated WHAT language that is...

Comment: mc is Movie Clip - he's talking about actionscript

Answer (score 0):

I think it will go something like that:

```
var valueOfWhatYouAreLookingFor = _root['send_'+event.currentTarget.name];
```

assuming that those vars are defined globally

PS. even if that will work (I don't have access to Flash to check this out) your structure has so many flows... for start with only one simple change you don't need global variables:

```
tabs_array = ["familiars","tallers2","gestions"];
for(var a=0; a<tabs_array.length; a++){
    this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].gotoAndStop("off");
    this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, act_over);
    this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, act_out);
    this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleAct);
    this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].buttonMode = true;
    // small addition
    this.popup_contact[tabs_array[a]].currentState = 'on';
}

function toggleAct(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // ...
    this.currentState = ( this.currentState == 'on' ? 'off' : 'on' );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I've never seen AS code like that with the ? and the colon so I'm not sure how to use it but I'll do some research. Thanks, I can see how would be less confusing.

Comment: look for "ternary operator"

Comment: It's just shorthand for `if-statement`. If the condition is true, return whatever is right behind the ?-sign, else return what is behind the :-sign